# Linux renaming now.jpg.1 to spy_1.html

Tags: linux

I want to use linux to rename 10 files.

*now.jpg to spy_.html*

And the other 9 should be

*now.jpg.1 to spy_html.1*

*now.jpg.2 to spy_html.2*

And so forth.

So far I have come up with this:

```
for f in *.jpg
do
mv “$f” “(“%s”%p”%i”%o”%n”%_).html”
done
```

But it doesn't work. Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expression to capture the optional numeric extension and add it to the target file name. This should work with bash:

```
for f in *.jpg*
do
  if [[ $f =~ now\.jpg(\.[0-9])? ]]; then
    mv "$f" "spy.html${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  fi
done
```

assuming you want `spy.html[.#]`. If you want an underscore for the files with the numerical extension, i.e. `spy_html.1`, it would be easier to issue two commands, one for `now.jpg` and one loop for the `now.jpg.*`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was stuck on how to go about. I went with the solution with two commands, because i specifically wanted the underscore aka spy_html.1